# Set character limit to display in a paragraph

Tags: jquery, json

I am pulling from a JSON feed and I just want to display a maximum of 10 characters of the string and then do a ... afterwards. How do I do that with JQuery?

Comment: You edit your question to include some of the code you have already written to get more responses.  +1 for brand new user getting down voted for no listed reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need jquery, JS can do that:

```
string.substr(start,length)

start   The index where to start the extraction. First character is at index 0
length  The number of characters to extract. If omitted, it extracts the rest of the string
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use CSS to set up an ellipsis:

```
.myparagraph {
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: 10em;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Then there's no need for any jQuery or other coding.

References:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html
- http://www.electrictoolbox.com/ellipsis-html-css/

(note that first link - [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is an excellent resource generally for CSS and Javascript stuff)

Comment: Cool use of CSS.  Didn't know about text-overflow, I'll have to learn more about it.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't checked this for off by one errors, so you might have to adjust for poor indexing.

```
var txt = SomeStringFromFeed;
if(txt.length > 10)
{
  txt = txt.substr(0,10) + "...";
}
return txt;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the CSS solution mentioned by @spudley is cross browser (no firefox support).  Assuming you care about that of course.  The first link he provides even states the limited support in the top right corner of the page.

Now, having said that I have a nice little function that may be overkill for what you need, but I have found I use this regularly in similar situations.  The code below has been commented, but what this does is it only inserts an ellipsis after the last full word based on the set limit.

So you can return "The dog jumps..." instead of "The dog Jumps ove..."

```
// ==============================================================================================
//  Truncate a string to the given length, breaking at word boundaries and adding an elipsis
//      @param str - String to be truncated
//      @param limit - integer Max length of the string
//      @returns a string
// ==============================================================================================

    function truncate(str, limit) {
        var chars;
        var i;

        // check if what was passed as a string is actually a string
        if ( typeof(str) != 'string') {
            return '';
        }

        // create an array of the chars in the string
        chars = str.split('');

        // if the length is greater than the set limit, process for truncating
        if (chars.length > limit) {
            // while the char count is greater than the limit,
            for (i = chars.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
                // if char count is still greater, redefine the array size to the value of i
                if (i > limit) {
                    chars.length = i;
                }
                // if char count is less than the limit keep going until you hit a space
                // and redefine the array size to the value of i
                else if (' ' === chars[i]) {
                    chars.length = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // add elipsis to the end of the array
            chars.push('...');
        }
        // return the array as a string
        return chars.join('');
    }
```

Comment: You're right of course, It isn't supported by Firefox *yet* (soon hopefully?). But all other browsers support it (even IE as far back as IE5.5), so it does have good coverage, and even Firefox does truncate it correctly. Plus there are hacky work-arounds to make it work in Firefox using XUL... but that's a whole other question and answer.

Comment: @Spudley it is a nice solution.  I Personally look forward to when this will function cross browser. I just wanted to make sure he/she (and anyone else that might stumble across this question for answers) was aware that if their needs require a cross browser solution that it may not work for them as hoped.

Answer (score 0):

[Truncate a string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301512/truncate-a-string-straight-javascript)