# Truncate string

Tags: javascript, jquery, truncate

I have a script:

```
  _content_insert: function () {
        var e = this,
            t = this.$tooltip.find(".tooltipster-content");        
        if (typeof e.Content === "string" && !e.options.contentAsHTML) {
            t.text(e.Content)
        } else {
            t.empty().append(e.Content)
        }
    },
```

and I'd like to truncate the Content to 140 characters.

I found a truncating script here - [Truncate a string straight javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301512/truncate-a-string-straight-javascript)

```
var length = 3;
var myString = "ABCDEFG";
var myTruncatedString = myString.substring(0,length);
```

How do I implement this into the code so that what comes out in (e.Content) is the truncated 140-character string?

Answer (score 0):

```
t.text(e.Content.substring(0,140));
```

Doesn't it work?

```
_content_insert: function () {
    var e = this,
        t = this.$tooltip.find(".tooltipster-content");        
    if (typeof e.Content === "string" && !e.options.contentAsHTML) {
        t.text(e.Content.substring(0,140))
    } else {
        t.empty().append(e.Content.substring(0,140))
    }
},
```

You can optimize the code. You can truncate after the string check and use that var.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
_content_insert: function () {
    var e = this,
        t = this.$tooltip.find(".tooltipster-content");        
    if (typeof e.Content === "string" && !e.options.contentAsHTML) {
        if(e.Content.length>140){
           t.text(e.Content.substring(0,140))
        }
        else{
           t.text(e.Content);
        }
    } else {
        t.empty().append(e.Content)
    }
},
```