# Can I limit the amount of characters within truncate? It cuts off too much

Tags: materialize

JS,

Is there a way I can load text either with truncate or JS but only let through a certain amount of characters? I'm using materializecss truncate but it cuts off way too early. Is there any control when it cuts off?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: Try [this JS method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301512/truncate-a-string-straight-javascript#answer-1301525)