# how to display specific number of letters of paragraph in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for solution to shortening paragraph in HTML

Let's say I have a paragraph
`<p>This is some text</p>`
Now what I want to know is how can I make this paragraph show less lines. For example instead of showing full paragraph it shows only first 4 characters which results in
`<p>This</p>`

Comment: What do you mean by "only show the first 4 characters" - because this question is only tagged as `html`, the solution here is to edit the HTML to only contain `<p>This</p>`. But I assume you're trying to do something like this in JavaScript or server-side rendering instead, in which case we'd need more information about what you've tried so far and what isn't working. If this `p` tag won't contain any other HTML tags, you could use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301512/truncate-a-string-straight-javascript for example.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want the full text output to the DOM but only want to visually show the first x characters, you could use CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow. Though that's not specific to the number of characters, rather the width of the element.

Comment: Do you mean to shorten in like that when displayed in a browser or inside your code editor (IDE) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:  https://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/

If you wanted to do it manually just store the text in globably js variable like:

```
var pText = "Some really long text that you want to shorten or lengthen on a click";

   $(".showMore").toggle(function() {
        //full text case
        $(".myParagraphElement").html(pText);
        // collapsed case, replace 50 with the number of characters you want
        $(".myParagraphElement").html(pText.substring(50));
    });
```

Comment: It works, however I have found shorter way using css (Thank you for help anyway)