# How can i truncate last line text and add more to it. - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

`<Text numberOfLines={2}> {myText} </Text>`

Then i have on press functionality as well for more/less but issue is more/less is coming on top of actual text but i want to reduce characters of text and append more to it.

Ex:
If I have text like this

`Hello, This is React Native. I want to format this.`
then I want it to be shown as this in 2 lines

`Hello, This is React Native.`

`I want to format... more`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301525/6672679

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.